# Apple Macbook MB467LL/A gray screen no apple logo HELP please

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, screen

New to the site, and I am having a little problem. My wife's Macbook has me stumped. It was working fine, (running Mavericks) and then just powered off. On powering back on we are now treated to a blank grey screen. I attempted resetting the PVRAM, and now we have the chime back, but still the grey screen, nothing else. So far I have attempted safe boot, verbose boot, single-user mode and I still have the grey screen.

I attempted to boot from my back USB, via the startup manager, and bootable media (c key) and same outcome... gray screen.

With the macbook being a few years old, and so far I've already replaced multiple parts (screen/power board/RAM) and with the Apple Care long gone, I really don't want to take it back to Apple. Last time we took it there, they wanted $800 to fix it, and it ended up costing me $10. Any suggestions are appreciated, as I will try anything to get it up and running again.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you get to the [Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't remember if I had, so I retried. Nothing happened. I got the chime, and then the continuous gray screen. If this is of any use, the disc drive has not been working for a while (makes horrific noises, and refuses to eject discs) and it kind of sounds like the tray is making a clicking/pulsing noise now when the mac is turned on and the gray screen appears. This happens every 3 seconds. My thought was to take the back off, and disconnect the disc drive, and see if this made any difference. I'm pretty sure it won't do anything, but I'm clutching at straws now.

Comment: I figured it. On taking apart, and having a better chance to listen to said sound, it was the hard drive. I put the hard drive from my mac in, and it booted no problems. Tried the suspect hard drive in my mac, and it was no go. I attempted to look for data using my enclosure, and I think it's goosed. Going to invest in a new hard drive, and a back up hard drive for any future mishaps. Thank you

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)